# Does the Red Rocket Mega Sign actually blast off / blow up in-game?

Tags: fallout-76

The 'Red Rocket Mega Sign' item in the Fallout 76 Atomic Shop is shown to be blasting off and then blowing up.

[image]

Does it actually do this in the game? If so, how?

Reference:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will take off/launch when another player destroys it. I've seen this done via hammer and shotgun.